# Python How to pass specific key from list of Dictionary to Map function

Tags: python, multithreading, map-function

I have data in below format:
and I have function which accepts 2 keyword argument
I am unable to come with syntax or example where i can pass specific keys from list of dictionaries  to Map function to run as multi threading

```py
import concurrent.futures

data = [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "org": "pqr"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "org": "sdf"
    }
    ]
def process_data(org_name, cu_name):
    print(org_name)
    print(cu_name)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as Executor:
   results = Executor.map(process_data, data)
```

Since data consists different key i need to map org to org_name , But I am not sure how to pass with map function

Comment: Easiest way would be to write a wrapper function which takes a dictionary from the list and calls `process_data`. The wrapper can then be used in the `map` call.

Comment: do you need `process_data` to accept exactly 2 params?

Comment: yes , That is requirement

Comment: @MichaelButscher , Can you suggest example of wrapper which can be combined with multi-threading

Comment: Something like `lambda d: process_data(d['org'], d['name'])`

Comment: I managed to do this below @MichaelButscher for wrapper idea


`import concurrent.futures
data = [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "org": "pqr"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "org": "sdf"
    }
    ]


def process_data(org_name, cu_name):
    print(f'org = {org_name}')
    print(f'cu ={cu_name}')

def wrapper(d:list):
    name = d['name']
    org = d['org']
    process_data(org_name= name,cu_name=org)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as Executor:
    results = Executor.map(wrapper, data)`

Answer (score 0):

When you use *data* as the iterable in *map()* what will happen is that each element in the list will be passed to process_data. That function only receives one parameter.

So...

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as TPE

data = [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "org": "pqr"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "org": "sdf"
    }
]

def process_data(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(f'{k} = {v}')

with TPE() as tpe:
    tpe.map(process_data, data)
```

...may help to clarify

Comment: correct and that is problem, I have another function which 2 parameter which i need to run as multi-threading and process it , example process data will run as thread

Answer (score 0):

Let your `process_data` function accept the needed keys `org` and `name`, so each input dictionary can be then unpacked (`**`) onto respective keys:

```
def process_data(org, name):
    print(org, name)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as Executor:
   results = Executor.map(lambda kargs: process_data(**kargs), data)
```

---

```
pqr abc
sdf xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import concurrent.futures

data = [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "org": "pqr"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "org": "sdf"
    }
]


def process_data(org_name, cu_name):
    print(f'org = {org_name}')
    print(f'cu ={cu_name}')



with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as Executor:
    result = Executor.map(lambda d: process_data(org_name=d['name'], cu_name=d['org']), data)
```

This worked for me thanks to Michael